Why when killing an app quickly, onStop and onPause are not called?
I want to schedule with WorkManager, and when I put the app into background, it will be scheduled, but if I kill the app too quickly, onStop and onPause will not be called, so it will not be possible to schedule in this situation. How can I solve it?
I used DefaultLifecycleObserver to listen to the state of the app and found that when killing the app quickly, onStop and onDestroy are not called.
private var defaultLifecycleObserver = object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    
    override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onDestroy(owner)
    }

    override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onStop(owner)
        NotificationManager.scheduleNotificationOffline()
    }

    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onResume(owner)
        NotificationManager.cancelWorkerReopen()
    }
}


What do you mean by "killing an app quickly"?

If you mean "swiping" app from recents then it causes entire app process to be force-stopped. There is no way to react to this.

yes, this is the situation, when swiping fast onStop and onDestroy will not be called.

onStop() is guaranteed to be called before the app is killed. onDestroy() will not be called. I've no idea why you think that onStop() is not being called.

Also, onPause() is guaranteed to be be called.
